# How to check server availability in Android?

Tags: android

`InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress( new byte[] { (byte) 192, (byte) 168, (byte) 254, (byte) 10 ); success = address.isReachable( 3000 );`

This returns false even though I am reasonably sure it is a reachable address.

I found that if I changed this to 127, 0, 0, 1 it returned success.

My next attempt was same code, but I used the address I got from a ping of www.google.com ( 72.167.164.64 as of this writing ). No success.

Comment: @jong you know about server ?

Comment: any server like my server address 192.168.11.231 .my data comes from this server address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a servlet/webpages or whatever you feel comfortable on the server that return ok or error depending on server status from your android you must call that url and check returned value, also on your try/catch you must watch specific exception for example related with timeout, also check for http status if your http request returned 200 then was ok and you can fetch server status from that url

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

```
boolean isOK = false;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://yourserverurl/yourstatusmethod");
    HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlcon.connect();
    if (urlcon.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            String serverStatus = readStream(in); //assuming that "http://yourserverurl/yourstatusmethod" returns OK or ERROR depending on your server status check         
            isOK = (serverStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"));
    }else{
      isOK = false;
    }

    url.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            isOK = false;
            e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
            isOK = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the readStream is a method that convert inputstream to string

```
public static String readStream (InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    for (int n; (n = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
        out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

this is just and idea.... there are a lot of ways to check server availability

Comment: ok thnx but you have any example of InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut) for understanding ..

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a server is available or not

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
```

Comment: can you explain using example?plz

Comment: this can work too xDDD because it Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name.The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address

Comment: R u sure @yeradis InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
 is working on android?

Comment: yes of course just check it here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: it Throws UnknownHostException if the address lookup fails.

Comment: @yeradis ok thnx but you have any example of InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut) for understanding ..

Comment: boolean isAvailable = false;
    try {
      isAvailable = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut);   
    }catch( UnknownHostException e ) {        
    }

Comment: host = yourservername and timeOut = howmuchtimeyouwanttowait

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4439/discussion-between-p-angre-and-yeradis)